# How can I disable options(scipen=999) for scientific notation in r?

Tags: r

I was trying to disable the scientific notation with the `options(scipen=999)` command. It worked fine for my plot but now I want to have the scientific notation again so I would like to disable that command.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `scipen` back to 0:

```
options(scipen = 0)
```